# How do I get the beep command working with the pcspkr module?

Tags: pulseaudio

The beep command only works when PulseAudio is not running. The pcspkr module is already loaded and the beep command only works when I run pulseaudio -k, but then it stops working after a few seconds when pulseaudio restarts. Is there a way to get the beep command to work while PulseAudio is running?

Comment: The beep command should be using the pc speaker module (which is not loaded in the kernel by default) and should be totally independent from pulseaudio and the sound system.  Are you sure your beep isn't emulating the pc speaker with a sound card module?

Comment: An alternative to beep is padsp which cooperates with pulseaudio.

Comment: it works when pulseaudio is not running

Comment: If it works when pulseaudio is not running then it isn't using the pc speaker module, but trying to access the sound card directly, bypassing pulseaudio.

Comment: What version of linux are you running?  Which of the many versions of beep are you using?